# Uncaught Exception: bind EADDRINUSE, but no process is found using that port

Tags: node.js, process, socket.io, port

I am building a Node.js application that makes use of a port. After closing the app and opening it again I get this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:20802
    at _handle.lookup (dgram.js:282:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Of course, I checked online and I saw that I should run the command `sudo lsof -t -i tcp:20802`, I tried `lsof -i:20802` and I also tried `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:20802)` to check/kill the process that is using the port, with no success. The weird part is that no process is found. I tried and rechecked several times with several tools, and it seems that the port is really not being used by any application.

Everytime I close the app I have a listener that executes a `client.stop()` so therefore, when quitting the application, I should not have any port open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This fails when running dgram's `.bind()`, I even tried freeing the port before binding with a library (kill-port) and it is still failing. Please check the images attached.

[image: I am killing the port before binding, and I am still getting an EADDRINUSE error]

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: you might be listening to same port somewhere else in your app. check your database connection

Comment: Given that the error comes from `dgram.js` it seems likely that this is a UDP port, not a TCP port.  So try `sudo lsof -t -i udp:20802`, or something like `netstat -an | grep 20802`

Comment: Thank you @ottomeister, I will try this command as soon as I get the error again. This is not happening in a database, but I will double check for any process which might be listening to the same port in the app. Thank you

Comment: Hi, @ottomeister, I just tried your solution. `sudo lsof -t -i udp:20802` did not help, but `netstat -an | grep 20802` did return the following line: `udp4  786818      0  *.20815                *.*` I am trying to kill whatever this is but I am still unable. I tried several ways of doing so, including using tools suck as kill-port and fkill-cli, but with no avail.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible sample for this?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, this happens when I'm running my project: https://github.com/jonybur/race-director; it uses a library I built: https://github.com/jonybur/f1-telemetry-client

I cant reproduce it without connecting the application to the game (it is an app to analize videogame data)

Comment: What OS are you using? Does it reproduce inside a VM with the same OS? Does it reproduce inside a VM with another OS? (I'm trying to eliminate the possibility of a kernel bug...)

Comment: @root MacOS, I have not reproduced this inside a VM, but I will give it a try and come back with results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to the socket with `exclusive: false`. The underlying TCP stack at a driver level supports socket options `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` (See the man page for more detail). This is to support the rebinding to the same port in a server implementation for instance.

From the node documentation:

> The options object may contain an additional exclusive property that is used when using dgram.Socket objects with the cluster module. When exclusive is set to false (the default), cluster workers will use the same underlying socket handle allowing connection handling duties to be shared. When exclusive is true, however, the handle is not shared and attempted port sharing results in an error.

```js
socket.bind({
  address: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  exclusive: false
});
```

Update:

Create the socket using `dgram.createSocket(options[, callback])` and set the option as described

> reuseAddr  When true socket.bind() will reuse the address, even if another process has already bound a socket on it. Default: false.

**References**:

- [SOCKET(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)
- [Node.js v12.7.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)

Comment: This might be it! I will try this and see if I can keep reproducing the bug after I set up `exclusive` to `false`.

Comment: @JonathanBursztyn did you manage to resolve this, also please upvote the answer if this was the solution.

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug again, therefore I am marking this as the correct response. Thank you.